# Meaning of “The sandpiper”

Tags: title, the-sandpiper

[The  Sandpiper](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandpiper) is a 1965 American drama film directed by Vincente Minnelli and starring Elizabeth Taylor and Richard Burton.

The movie is about an improbable love story between a painter (Liz Tailor) and a school director (Richard Burton).

How is the movie title related to the movie? The sandpiper is a a wading bird with a long bill and typically long legs.
I could not find other meanings about the sandpiper. How does it relate to the movie?

Comment: Isn't this explained in the very same Wikipedia article you've linked to?

Comment: @F1Krazy really? I checked but I could not  find it.

Comment: Did you check [the section named "Title"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandpiper#Title)?

Comment: @F1Krazy I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandpiper):

> ##### Title
>
> The character Laura Reynolds nurses a sandpiper with a broken wing, as Edward Hewitt looks on. The bird lives in her home until it is healed and then flies free, though it comes back occasionally. This sandpiper is used as a central symbol in the movie, illustrating the themes of growth and freedom.